# Imported workflow activated as feature does not show up in Manage site features page

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to move a workflow  (reusable workflow bound to a content type)  from one site collection to antoher.

As a site collection admin, i saved the workflow as a template in SP Designer, saved the .wsp file and uploaded it on the target collection, and activate the solution.

When I look for it Manage site features page, i can't see the wokflow, in order to activate it.

I did the same solution importation and activation in Central Administratrion but wihout succes : it  doesn't show up in the Manage site features page.

I also run the Enable-SPFeature command in the SP Management Shell and is has sucesfully activated the feature.  Still it dont's show in the Manage site features page, and the workflow does not appear when i try to associate it to a library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the sites in different languages? If so you can solve it by importing the .wsp in Visual Studio (Import SharePoint Solution Package NOT Import Reusable Workflow) and remove the resource file.

To do this:

- with SharePoint Designer, export the reusable workflow (using Save As Template) as a .wsp and save the file on your development machine
- create a New Project in Visual Studio, select "Import SharePoint Solution Package"
- type the name of your new solution
- in step 2 of the wizard, browse to the .wsp you saved in the first step
- click finish
- in the Solution Explorer find the Features node and open Feature1
- find the resources.XXX.resx file (XXX is the language) and Delete it

You can make other changes the project while it's open in Visual Studio, you could change the feature name and description for example, and even edit the workflow but there are [caveats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff358272.aspx)

You can use F5 to deploy the workfow and test it. After you confirmed everything still works right-click on the project and select 'Package' to create your new .wsp in the bin directory of the project.

Comment: Thanks, i think you founded the probem, indeed the languages are different. Could you help with describing the steps in Visual Studio (which ressource file to remove, how to republish the workflow). Thank you.

Comment: Sure, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks again, yes it helped suceeded in migrating the workflow.

Comment: I still  have a problem though when migrating : the source workflow (the one that has to be migrated) is a globaly reusable one, and when i transform it (copy workflow with SP Designer) to reusable only (in order to be able to save it as a solution template) i loose all the task fom fields and rules inside the infopath taks form. Do you know by any chance how this can be avoided ? (this occurs when i am doing a copy/modify workflow in SP designer). Thanks

Comment: Not sure, I have not tried a globally reusable workflow. I have moved between Server and Foundation and found the only way to get rid of some problems was to re-type the whole workflow... You may want to open a new question, since this is a different problem.